# SQL Server: First number above an amount within a string

Tags: sql-server, string, numbers

I have fields with a string of numbers.  I have code to extract the first number `(CONVERT([int],left([Times],(2))))`, but I also need code to extract the first number above 45 e.g.

```
10 20 50 60 70
11 80
34 47
20
30 60 80
```

Type: varchar.

To return:

```
50
80
47
Null
60
```

Due to the strings being different lengths, I'm struggling to come up with a workable solution.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sql Server versión ?

Comment: Does numbers are always split by single space ' ' ?

Comment: SQL Server 2017, Numbers are split by a single space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use a JSON-based approach. You need to transform the input data into a valid JSON array with string replacement (`10 20 50 60 70` is transformed into `[10,20,50,60,70]`):

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (
   TextData varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO Data
   (TextData)
VALUES   
   ('10 20 50 60 70'),
   ('11 80'),
   ('34 47'),
   ('20'),
   ('30 60 80')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT d.TextData, j.[value]
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT TOP(1) [value]
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', REPLACE(d.TextData, ' ', ','), ']'))
   WHERE CONVERT(int, [value]) > 45
   ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key])
) j
```

Result:

```
---------------------
TextData        value
---------------------
10 20 50 60 70  50
11 80           80
34 47           47
20  
30 60 80        60
```

Comment: Thank you.  Found a few stray commas and full stops and so did a triple replace.  Works great.

Comment: On the above solution, I've made some edits to do a count. `Count(j.[value])` in the Select statement and `group by d.TextData` and increasing the `Top(1)` to `Top(10)` as my string has a max of 10 numbers.  It works fine but wondering if there a simpler way to count the numbers in the string >45.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: @Seale,  `SELECT d.TextData, j.[value] FROM Data d OUTER APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value] FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT('[', REPLACE(d.TextData, ' ', ','), ']')) WHERE CONVERT(int, [value]) > 45) j` is another option.

Comment: A lot cleaner.  Thank you.